# How to use initialFiles in material-ui-dropzone

Tags: reactjs

How to use initialFiles in material-ui-dropzone i dont know method to use initialFiles_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {DropzoneArea} from 'material-ui-dropzone'

class DropzoneAreaExample extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      files: []
    };
  }
  handleChange(files){
    this.setState({
      files: files
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <DropzoneArea
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        initialFiles
        />
    )
  }
}

export default DropzoneAreaExample;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<DropzoneArea initialFiles={[url]} ... />
```